# How can I pass data between multiple invocations of PHP's eval()?

Tags: php, eval

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin that needs to tailor part of its output to be compatible with a page caching plugin (W3 Total Cache). The technique used by the caching plugin to cache most of the page and only execute fragments is to `eval()` such code fragments.

However, as my plugin may be invoked in several places within a Wordpress template, I need to keep state between these different instances of my code being `eval()`-executed. Basically I need the first piece of code to save data that the other code fragments will then use.

Essentially I need the code in the `eval()` to access data outside of the `eval()`.

Are there any methods of doing this?

EDIT: I should probably add that each execution of `eval()` is also wrapped in a function that is called as a callback from `preg_replace_callback()`, so any variables set in the `eval()` would need to persist through that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[eval()](http://php.net/eval) does not create a new variable scope:

```
<?php

$foo = 'Hello, World!';
eval('var_dump($foo); $bar = 33;');
var_dump($bar);
```

... prints this:

```
string(13) "Hello, World!"
int(33)
```

I'd say all your problem is being able to create global variables from within a function. You can use the usual approaches: [global](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword or [$GLOBALS](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array.